# iPad to view LAN local domains?

Tags: ipad, macos, web-sharing

I have multiple local domains (i.e. localtest.local) that my iPad cannot see.  My machine name, alpha.local, has Apache directives to a "site" I have on the box.  All are in /Library/WebServer/Documents/, and I have other directives to many local domains.

I have an Airport Extreme router, which I think the iPad should get some answers from, but it doesn't have anything where I can shove this reference to.

Kind of stuck.  Any ideas how I can get my iPad to see localtest.local?

Answer (score 1):

Truth is you should have a local DNS Server that you share out using DHCP to all your clients.  This way you can manage local DNS records on your local network.  I will confess there might be a better way, but this is what came to mind off the top of my head

Comment: Hi there.  I do have a local DNS.  I use internal static IP's using my DNS on a server internally.  I've entered the secondary zone for this "domain" localtest.local, and pointed it to my workstation.  Still no luck.